# Removing all copies of the SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

In loop I have this line and I need to remove all copies. How would I be able to do this in Swift in SpriteKit?

```
obstacles = obstaclesImage.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name your nodes:

```
obstacleCopy.name = "obstacleCopy"
```

Then enumerate their parent:

```
self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("obstacleCopy") {
    node, stop in 
    node.removeFromParent()
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much :)